# Match multiple cells, then complete a lookup

Tags: excel, if-statement, indexing, match, vlookup

I'm looking for a formula that will lookup a value in a column, then return a value if the date is equal to or between two dates.

For example, in the attached picture, the formula would go in C2.
[image]

I want to lookup B2&A2 (280002443601) in a column on another tab.
If 280002443601 is located in the column on the other tab and the date in C1 (1/18/24) is between the dates in the same row on the other tab, I want to return a value in another column on the other tab.
I would then copy down the formula for 280002443602, 280002443603, etc.

If 280002443602 is in column AL (AL20) and 1/18/24 is equal to or between the dates in columns AR and AS, I want to return the value in column AU20, which would be 1,427.
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I tried the attached formula and it seemed to work, but won't copy.
Also, if I change the lookup value the formula will not adjust.
For example, 280002443602 to 280002443603.
[image]

Comment: joining criteria aka matching several things can be seen in this example, there re many others on here. https://stackoverflow.com/q/40089611/4961700

Comment: What's up with AL15:AL17 having the same code? Would there be a need then to check several rows if there are duplicates?

Comment: The same material is running on different lines. I have combined the material and line numbers. For the example, material 28000244 is running on both lines 3602 and 3603. On both of these lines, I want to return the value in column AU for line 3602 (1/19/24 - 2/24/24) and for line 3603 (1/19/24 - 2/27/24.

Comment: Ah, so you want to search in between the start of the first found value and the end of the last-found value. Though in your comment, I suppose you meant for line 3603 (1/19/24 - 2/13/24), not that it matters for the AU value but your "Both" value is different at row 30..